# remove character on the last line that specific word appears

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

we have the following file example

we want to remove the `,`  character on the last line that `topic` word exists

```
more file

{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":84,"replicas":[1006,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":85,"replicas":[1001,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":86,"replicas":[1002,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":87,"replicas":[1003,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":88,"replicas":[1004,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":89,"replicas":[1005,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":90,"replicas":[1006,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":91,"replicas":[1001,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":92,"replicas":[1002,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":93,"replicas":[1003,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":94,"replicas":[1004,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":95,"replicas":[1005,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":96,"replicas":[1006,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":97,"replicas":[1001,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]},
```

expected output

```
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":84,"replicas":[1006,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":85,"replicas":[1001,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":86,"replicas":[1002,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":87,"replicas":[1003,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":88,"replicas":[1004,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":89,"replicas":[1005,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":90,"replicas":[1006,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":91,"replicas":[1001,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":92,"replicas":[1002,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":93,"replicas":[1003,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":94,"replicas":[1004,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":95,"replicas":[1005,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":96,"replicas":[1006,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":97,"replicas":[1001,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]}
```

---

sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: Rather than modifying some broken JSON, would it not be better to generate correct JSON from the start?

Comment: I assume you can't just address the line using `$` because there's other stuff after (and possibly before) the lines shown here?

Comment: no , the topic word exists  only on the following lines that mentioned in the quastion

Comment: Are these lines part of a bigger JSON document that you want to extract this data out of?  As with your other recent questions, that would be trivial with `jq`, or any other JSON parser.

Comment: Are these lines part of a bigger JSON document that you want to extract - NO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU sed and tac:

```
tac bad.json | sed '0,/"topic"/s/,$//' | tac
```

If the line has trailing whitespace, change the pattern to `,[[:blank:]]*$`

Comment: it will be more elegant to use sed - i ,

Comment: @yael `-i` isn't really compatible with pipelines

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
sed -i '${s/,[[:blank:]]*$//}' file
```

This command replace the file *on the fly*.

Comment: not works  , I try it on linux redhat machine

Comment: Have you tried to do `cat file` to check ? :D

Comment: also not works , !

Comment: also the update not works

Comment: The code have not changed. Are you passing the good file to the command ? Is this works ? `sed -n '${s/,$//};p' file`

Comment: also not works , sorry

Comment: Could you please edit your original POST and add this info: `sed --version` ?

Comment: sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: sorry but its not remove the ","

Comment: @yael This _definitely_ works given a file such as the one in your question.  If it does not work for you, then your data is not what you show in the question, which casts doubt on whether or not you are actually showing the data that you are working on or not.

Comment: Trailing CR on every line ??

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed` in extended regex mode `-r` we can do it as follows:

```
sed -ri -e '
   /"topic"/{
      x;1!p;ba
   }
   H;1h;:a;$!d;g
   //s/^([^\n]+),(\n|$)/\1\2/
' file
```

The basic idea is to collect lines starting from `"topic"` containing line
 to the next (howsoever farther away it may be) into the hold space. then 
when we eventually arrive at the eof, we remove the `,` from the end of 
line (=> "topic" line was the last line) or from the first newline 
(=> "topic" was last in the file but was followed by some more non-topic 
lines before we hit the eof.)

Answer (score 0):

command

```
sed '$s/,$//g' filename
```

output

```
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":84,"replicas":[1006,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":85,"replicas":[1001,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":86,"replicas":[1002,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":87,"replicas":[1003,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":88,"replicas":[1004,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":89,"replicas":[1005,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":90,"replicas":[1006,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":91,"replicas":[1001,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":92,"replicas":[1002,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":93,"replicas":[1003,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":94,"replicas":[1004,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":95,"replicas":[1005,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":96,"replicas":[1006,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":97,"replicas":[1001,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Done in python method

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r',$')
t=open('filename','r')
l=[]
for i in t:
    l.append(i.strip())
for h in range(0,len(l),1):
    if (h <15):
        print l[h]
    else:
        print re.sub(k,"",l[h])
```

output

```
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":84,"replicas":[1006,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":85,"replicas":[1001,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":86,"replicas":[1002,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":87,"replicas":[1003,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":88,"replicas":[1004,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":89,"replicas":[1005,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":90,"replicas":[1006,1004]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":91,"replicas":[1001,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":92,"replicas":[1002,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":93,"replicas":[1003,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":94,"replicas":[1004,1002]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":95,"replicas":[1005,1003]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":96,"replicas":[1006,1005]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":97,"replicas":[1001,1006]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":98,"replicas":[1002,1001]},
{"topic":"life_is_hard","partition":99,"replicas":[1003,1002]}
```